# SQLAlchemy ordered tree structure using association proxy object for positioning

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, associations, relationship

I'm trying to create a simple tree structure of tasks. A Task can have a state (done:boolean) and a title (title:string) and any number of subtasks (tasks:Task[]). I've successfully managed to create a Task object and the association proxy object PositionedTask. The parent/child relationship seems to work, allthough the positioning is unused.

This is the code I've got so far:

```
import sys

from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import Integer
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy import Boolean
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import backref
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy.ext.orderinglist import ordering_list

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()


class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String, nullable=False)
    done = Column(Boolean, nullable=True, default=False)

    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tasks.id'))
    tasks = association_proxy('tasks_positioned', 'task')

    def __init__(self, title=None, done=False):
        self.title = title
        self.done = done

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Task #{0} \'{1}\' done={2}>'.format(self.id, self.title, self.done)



class PositionedTask(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tasks_subtasks'
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tasks.id'), primary_key=True)
    task_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tasks.id'), primary_key=True)
    position = Column(Integer, default=0, nullable=False)

    parent = relationship(Task, foreign_keys='PositionedTask.parent_id', backref=backref('tasks_positioned', cascade='all, delete-orphan'))
    task = relationship(Task, foreign_keys='PositionedTask.task_id')

    def __init__(self, task=None, parent=None, position=None):
        self.task = task
        self.parent = parent
        self.position = position

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<PositionedTask parent=\'{0}\' task=\'{1}\' position={2}>'.format(
            self.parent.title, self.task.title, self.position
        )


def main(argv=sys.argv):
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.db', echo=False)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    session = Session(engine)

    task = Task('Parent')
    child1 = Task('Child #1', done=True)
    child2 = Task('Child #2')
    grandchild1 = Task('GrandChild #1')

    child1.tasks.append(grandchild1)
    task.tasks.append(child1)
    task.tasks.append(child2)

    session.add(task)
    session.commit()

    task = session.query(Task).filter(Task.id==1).first()
    print task
    for st in task.tasks:
        print st
    for pst in task.tasks_positioned:
        print pst

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output of the current application is:

```
<Task #1 'Parent' done=False>
<Task #2 'Child #1' done=True>
<Task #4 'Child #2' done=False>
<PositionedTask parent='Parent' task='Child #1' position=0>
<PositionedTask parent='Parent' task='Child #2' position=0>
```

How can I mix in sqlalchemy.ext.orderinglist.ordering_list to this code to have my subtasks automatically positioned?

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the `backref` part of the `PositionedTask.parent` relationship, and voila:

```
parent = relationship(
    Task,
    foreign_keys='PositionedTask.parent_id',
    backref=backref(
        'tasks_positioned',
        order_by ="PositionedTask.position", # @new:
        collection_class=ordering_list('position'), # @new:
        cascade='all, delete-orphan'),
    )
```